# How to download a list of videos on sdcard and play on videoview?

Tags: android, android-videoview, download

I have used a videoview to play the video from raw folder locally, but now im trying to download a list of videos first on sdcard and after to play it to media player.  Here is my videoview.

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
/* Full Screen Mode-Sticky */
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    if (hasFocus) {
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);}
}



public void downloadVideoFile(String url, String dest_file_name) {
    try {

        URL domain = new URL("http://192.168.0.22");
        String video_folder = "video";
        String sdcard_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        String dest_video_path = sdcard_path + File.separator + video_folder + File.separator + dest_file_name;
        File dest_file = new File(dest_video_path);
        URL u = new URL(domain + "/files/video/");
        URLConnection conn = u.openConnection();
        int contentLength = conn.getContentLength();
        DataInputStream stream = new DataInputStream(u.openStream());
        byte[] buffer = new byte[contentLength];
        stream.readFully(buffer);
        stream.close();
        DataOutputStream fos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(dest_file));
        fos.write(buffer);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();

    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {

        return;

    } catch (IOException e) {

        return;

    }
}


private VideoView myVideo1;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String video_folder = "myvideos";
    String sdcard_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    File fvideo_path = new File(sdcard_path + File.separator + video_folder);
    File videolist[] = fvideo_path.listFiles();
    String play_path = videolist[0].getAbsolutePath();

    myVideo1=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
    myVideo1.setVideoPath(play_path);
    myVideo1.start();
    myVideo1.requestFocus();

    myVideo1.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.setLooping(true);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: build video list from a specific path on sdcard

```
String video_folder = "myvideos";
String sdcard_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

File fvideo_path = new File(sdcard_path + File.separator + video_folder);

File videolist[] = fvideo_path.listFiles();
```

Step 2: play any video in list by index

```
//you can next or prev index from 0 - list lenght;
String play_path = videolist[0].getAbsolutePath();
```

Step 3: you set play_path to media player

```
   myVideo1.setVideoPath(play_path);
   myVideo1.start();
   myVideo1.requestFocus();
```

Example code to download file from server:

```
public void downloadVideoFile(String url, String dest_file_name) {
          try {


              String video_folder = "myvideos";
              String sdcard_path = nvironment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
              String dest_video_path = sdcard_path + File.separator + video_folder + File.separator + dest_file_name;
              File dest_file = new File(dest_video_path);
              URL u = new URL(url);
              URLConnection conn = u.openConnection();
              int contentLength = conn.getContentLength();
              DataInputStream stream = new DataInputStream(u.openStream());
              byte[] buffer = new byte[contentLength];
              stream.readFully(buffer);
              stream.close();
              DataOutputStream fos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(dest_file));
              fos.write(buffer);
              fos.flush();
              fos.close();

          } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {

              return; 

          } catch (IOException e) {

              return; 

          }
    }
```

Comment: How to download it first from server..Which technique is better ?

Comment: please look my updated code, still doesnt work. 
I think i have done something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I am using below code to get download videos from Server

```
class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<Object, String, Integer> {



        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();


        }


        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();

        }

        /**
         * Downloading file in background thread
         * */
        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Object... params) {

            try {

                URL url = new URL((String) params[1]);

                name = ((String) params[1]).substring(((String) params[1])
                        .lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                // Log.v("log_tag", "name Substring ::: " + name);
                URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                conection.connect();
                // getting file length
                int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

                // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),
                        8192);
                File download = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/download/");
                if (!download.exists()) {
                    download.mkdir();
                }
                String strDownloaDuRL = download + "/" + name;
                Log.v("log_tag", " down url   " + strDownloaDuRL);
                FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(strDownloaDuRL);

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                }
                // flushing output
                output.flush();

                // closing streams
                output.close();
                input.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }
            return 0;

        }




        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

         // Do after downloaded file

        }

    }
```

Comment: How to set the server url? Sorry but im just a beginner.